# Is there a limit in a point surrounded by a role?

Tags: calculus

I've already seen when we do the limit of a point even if it is out of the domain, but if its surrounds too? 
A function F that is not defined on a open interval 
"I" =  ]-1,1[
Exist the limit of F, as x aproaches 0?

Comment: A limit point x of a set needs to have points of the set that are different from it, but are arbitrarily close to it. If there are no other points of the set within a neighborhood of x then x is not a limit point of that set. Even so , if x is itself a member of the set then the sequence x,x,x,... is indeed a sequence of points in the set that converges to x.

Comment: Do you know where you red this? I dont know how to search this in the web,

Comment: Here is a description of "limit point" in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point